# Another (perhaps tricky) integral.

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

While solving my Math paper, I came across this integral, and I can't see any way to solve it. At least, any easy way. The integral is-

$$
\int{x^{2} \over 1 + x^{5}}\,\mathrm{d}x
$$

I'm not even sure it exists, by the looks of it. Any help ?.

Comment: It has a *very* messy anti-derivative.

Comment: The answer is $\frac{\mathrm{log}\left( 2\,{x}^{2}+\left( \sqrt{5}-1\right) \,x+2\right) }{5-{5}^{\frac{3}{2}}}+\frac{\mathrm{log}\left( 2\,{x}^{2}+\left( -\sqrt{5}-1\right) \,x+2\right) }{{5}^{\frac{3}{2}}+5}-\frac{2\,\mathrm{atan}\left( \frac{4\,x+\sqrt{5}-1}{\sqrt{2\,\sqrt{5}+10}}\right) }{\sqrt{5}\,\sqrt{2\,\sqrt{5}+10}}+\frac{2\,\mathrm{atan}\left( \frac{4\,x-\sqrt{5}-1}{\sqrt{10-2\,\sqrt{5}}}\right) }{\sqrt{5}\,\sqrt{10-2\,\sqrt{5}}}+\frac{\mathrm{log}\left( x+1\right) }{5}$ (I got the computer to do it for me!)

Comment: @smcc This doesn't help anyone.

Comment: @KingDuken Not necessarily. The presence of so many logs and arctans suggests a possible partial fraction approach

Comment: Doesn't it help to know what the answer should be? The poster wasn't sure it existed. (I did not post it as an answer.)

Comment: @Brenton, True but if Rip Tide wanted to use Wolfram Alpha, they wouldn't be asking what to do on this website. I just find it inconclusive that someone would give an answer but not explain how to answer the question properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have
$$x^5+1 = (x+1)(x^4-x^3+x^2-x+1) = (x+1)(x^2+ax+1)(x^2-bx+1)$$
where $a-b=-1$ and $ab=1$.

Now use partial fractions and proceed.

Comment: Tedious, but it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I have the following rather lengthy approach: Initially, we note that the integral does not exist due to the pole at x=-1. However, $\int_0^\infty x^2/x^5 dx$ exists since $|x|^2/|x|^5 \le |x|^2$ for sufficiently large $|x| > 0$. I think, we can deal with this integral using the Residue theorem from function theory: f(z):= z^2/(1+z^5) is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}$ except for the roots of $(1+z^5)$ which are given as
$$ a_k = e^{\pi i/5} e^{2\pi i k/5} \qquad k=0,...,4.$$
Consider the path
$$\gamma_R:= \alpha_R * \beta_R * \tilde\alpha_R$$
(first go $\alpha_R$ then $\beta_R$...) with
$$\alpha_R(t) = R t \qquad t \in [0,1]$$
$$\beta_R(t) = Re^{it} \qquad t \in [0, 2\pi/5]$$
$$\tilde\alpha_R(t) = (1-t)Re^{2\pi i/5} \qquad t\in [0,1]$$
for $R>1$. $\gamma_R$ goes a around a segment of B_R(0) which only encloses $a_0$. Therefore the Residue theorem yields
$$2\pi i Res_{a_0}f = \int_{\gamma_R}f(z)\, dz = \int_{\alpha_R}f + \int_{\beta_R}f + \int_{\tilde \alpha_R}f$$
Using Cauchys inequality from function theory the middle integral goes to 0 for $R\to \infty$. Now it can be shown that (found in most textbooks)
$$Res_{a_0}f = a_0^2/(5a_0^4) = 1/5 a_0^{-2} = 1/5 e^{-2/5 \pi i}.$$
and then
$$2/5 \pi i e^{-2/5 \pi i} = \int_0^R x^2/(1+x^5) dx - \int_0^R e^{2/5\pi i}\frac{(te^{2/5\pi i})^2}{1+(te^{2/5\pi i})^5} dt \\
= (1-e^{6/5\pi i})\int_0^R x^2/(1+x^5) dx \to (1-e^{6/5\pi i})\int_0^\infty x^2/(1+x^5) dx$$
for $R\to \infty$. Therefore
$$ \int_0^\infty x^2/(1+x^5) dx = \frac{2/5\pi i e^{-2/5\pi i}}{(1- e^{6/5\pi i})} = \frac{\pi/5}{1/(2i)(e^{2/5\pi i} - e^{8/5\pi i})} = \frac{\pi/5}{\sin(2/5 \pi)}$$
I have compared this to the result form wolfram alpha and it checks out. I hope I could help.

BS

Comment: This is similar to [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/176216).  However, is the question asking for a definite integral?

Comment: I thought the author of the question asked for the integral $\int x^2/(1+x^5)dx = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x^2/(1+x^5)dx$ for which I tried to provide an answer. I'm sory in case I misunderstood.